# Transaction Builder Won't Accept An Empty String

Tags: gnosis-safe

Essentially, as the title suggests, I need to build a transaction where one of the inputs, a string, needs to be empty. Trying various things like '0x' or '""' as inputs just makes them read as a string, but I need a length 0 string in order to pass the decision tree in the destination contract. If the field is left blank, the transaction builder will not create the transaction and just rejects the click.

How do I enter an empty string

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem linked to Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page.

Hope it helps, Louis